# Injection III : Interposable conflict with BitCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-injection

I am using [InjectionIII](https://github.com/johnno1962/InjectionIII) for code injection on Xcode 11.5 and MacOS 10.15.2. Setup guide says

> To use injection, download the app from the App Store and run it. Then, you must add **"-Xlinker -interposable"** to your project's **"Other Linker Flags" for the Debug target (qualified by the simulator SDK to avoid complications with bitcode).**

I added flag as shown in screen shot, It runs fine on Simulator but for Device I get this error.

```
-interposable and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
```

There is something wronng the way I have setup flags but I can't figure it out.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently InjectionIII can only work on simulators<sup>[1](https://github.com/johnno1962/InjectionIII/issues/214)</sup>. So you may want to specify "Other Linker Flags" only for simulators to prevent build error. Click the "+" icon in your image to select a target<sup>[2](https://github.com/johnno1962/InjectionIII/issues/128#issuecomment-661343221)</sup>:

[image: Any iOS Simulator SDK]